# Find the Sum of points, grouping & display each Class

Tags: mysql

my table

```
+----+-------+------+---------+--------+------+
| ID | CLASS | NAME | SCHOOL  | POINTS | YEAR |
+----+-------+------+---------+--------+------+
|  1 |     5 | S1   | School1 |      5 | 2013 |
|  2 |     6 | S2   | School1 |      0 | 2013 |
|  3 |     5 | S3   | School2 |      1 | 2014 |
|  4 |     6 | S4   | School1 |      3 | 2013 |
|  5 |     6 | S5   | School2 |      1 | 2014 |
|  6 |     5 | S6   | School1 |      0 | 2013 |
|  7 |     6 | S7   | School2 |      3 | 2013 |
|  8 |     6 | S8   | School1 |      5 | 2013 |
|  9 |     5 | S9   | School1 |      1 | 2014 |
| 10 |     5 | S10  | School1 |      0 | 2013 |
| 11 |     6 | S11  | School2 |      5 | 2014 |
| 12 |     5 | S12  | School1 |      1 | 2013 |
+----+-------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

Here I would like to find Total points of a School with respect of Class and Year ordering by highest points.

my Problem, need to display, Class 5, 6 points also in the Total points.

I am using following code.

```
 SELECT School, SUM(Points) as Total  FROM students WHERE Year='2013' 
 GROUP BY School ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 6
```

Fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b000/2

So my Final output looks:

```
 +---------+-------+
 | SCHOOL  | TOTAL |
 +---------+-------+
 | School1 |    14 |
   Class 5       6
   Class 6       8

 | School2 |     3 |
   Class 5       0
   Class 6       3
 +---------+-------+
```

Please help. Sorry for the poor english.

Comment: Why do you call the column `School` and you show classes in your output? That doesn't make sense

Comment: Class 5 and Class 6 aren't members of the SCHOOL column..

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 as seq, School, School AS Class, SUM(Points) as Total
      FROM students
     WHERE Year='2013'
     GROUP BY seq, School
   UNION
    SELECT 2 as seq, School, class, SUM(points) as total
      FROM students
     WHERE year='2013'
     GROUP BY seq, school, class
) AS temp
ORDER BY School, seq, Total DESC
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b000/37

Note: I believe you would be better off selecting the raw data and have the reporting tool take care of aggregating and summarizing the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
row_number,
case when class = '' then School else Class end as School,
Total
from
(
    select
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,
    a.*
    from
        (
        SELECT 
        School, '' as Class, SUM(Points) as Total  
        FROM students WHERE Year = 2013
        group by School
        union all
        select
        School, Class, sum(Points) as Total
        from students where year = 2013
        group by
        School, Class
    ) a
    JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
    order by School, Class, Total desc
) a
order by row_number
```